# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I just upgraded to Spark 2.1.0 and decided to test out my data with beeline, but for some reason it gives me:

> Error:
>   org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging was removed
>   in Spark 2.0. Please check if your library is compatible with Spark
>   2.0 (state=,code=0)

I renamed the old directory so all files would be new. I'm not running my own code, but beeline that comes with Spark.

Here are steps that I followed:

```
cd /usr/local/spark
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://REMOVED:7077 --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 6G --executor-cores 6 --executor-memory 14G --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10015 --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.4-s_2.11 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=REMOVED --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=REMOVED --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=REMOVED
./bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://REMOVED:10015
```

So I'm not very sure what to do now, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `datastax:spark-cassandra-connector` also. Please, try:

```
--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-M3-s_2.11
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine! I chose 1.6.4 because it's the first version that shows up here: https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector which is why I thought it was latest and I thought 2.0.0 was a beta version or something.